# Two instances of keyword auto in cpp

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, maps, auto

First one being:

```
map <int,int> m;
//... some elements inserted
auto i= m.begin();
cout<<(*i).first<<(*i).second;
```

Here we are required to use the dereference operator *
Second:

```
map <int,int> m;
//... some elements inserted
for(auto i: m)
cout<<i.first<<i.second;
```

Why am I not required to use the * operator this time?
One more doubt:

```
for(auto &i: m)
```

what difference does '&' make here?

Comment: `auto i= m.begin();` <=> `std::map<int, int>::iterator i = m.begin ();` | `for(auto i: m)` <=> `for (std::map<int, int>::value_type i : m)` | `for(auto &i: m)` <=> `for (std::map<int, int>::value_type& i : m)`

Comment: whats value_type ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: `auto` just deduces the type for you automatically. In the first example you have an iterator that points to a key-value pair, in the second there is no iterator. Just a key-value pair. Also, you should use `i->first` instead of `(*i).first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto i=m.begin()` will give you iterator .. which is accessed more like a pointer (syntactically)  when you want to access the value...

`for(auto i:m)` will copy current element of `m` (a pair) into `i` , `i` is a copy of element, not the element itself...

`for (auto &i: m)` will work on a reference, the original map is affected

Comment: ok. So 'i' acts like a pointer to a new pair. am I right?

Comment: i=m.begin() gives you iterator,, calling an iterator a pointer wont be justified. Ita a good time to read about iterator https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/   ..... Iterator are more for containers ..... Or are you talking about the for(auto & i:m) ??

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Comment: :) welcome ,, if you are satisfied please accept the answer and close. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the below code snippet, the first `i` is of type iterator where as the `i` in the for loops are of pair type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <int,int> m;
    m[1] = 5;
    m[10] = 60;
    m[100] = 800;
    // Below i is map iterator (std::map<int, int>::iterator)
    auto i = m.begin();
    std::cout << typeid(i).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << (*i).first << " : " << (*i).second << '\n';
    std::cout << i->first << " : " << i->second << '\n';

    for(auto i: m) {
        // Below i is pair<int, int>
        std::cout << typeid(i).name() << '\n';
        std::cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << '\n';
    }
    for(auto& i: m) {
        // Below i is reference of pair<int, int>)
        // modifying this would result in updated values in the map.
        std::cout << typeid(i).name() << '\n';
        std::cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mital! that helps